# Add observation to the end of the table SAS

Tags: sas

Let say I have a table like:

```
Z 25  26  27 ... 100
0 300 200 200    100
1 278 262 177     45
2 168 222 122     22
```

(The 1st line is also the header).

Now I want to add more 20 observations in my table:

```
Z 25  26  27 ... 100
0 300 200 200    100
1 278 262 177     45
2 168 222 122     22
3 84  111  61     11
...
22 84  111  61     11
```

So that (all observation with Z=3 to 22) = (observation with Z = 2) * 1/2. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Please remember to show what you've tried so far per the SO guidelines [ask]

Answer (score 2):

The special variable name list `_numeric_` is used to array all the numeric variables.  A loop over that array will let you divide each variable of a selected row by `2`.

Example:

```
data have;
input Z _25  _26  _27 _100;
datalines;
0 300 200 200    100
1 278 262 177     45
2 168 222 122     22
run;

data newrows(drop=last_z);
  set have nobs=nobs point=nobs;   * read last row;

  last_z = z;

  array _ _numeric_;               * array all numeric variables;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(_);            
    _(_n_) = _(_n_) / 2;           * divide each variable by 2;
  end;

  do z = last_z + 1 to last_z + 20;  * output 20 'new' rows;
    output;  
  end;

  stop;
run;

proc append base=have data=newrows;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, a SAS variable name can not be a number. However, this gives you what you want

```
data have;
input z a b c;
datalines;
0 300 200 200
1 278 262 177
2 168 222 122
;

data want;
   set have end=lr;
   array arr a--c;
   output;
   if lr;
   do over arr;
      arr = arr / 2;
   end;
   do _N_ = 1 to 20;
      z + 1;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Updated Code:

```
data have;
   do z = 0, 1, 2;
      array arr _25-_100;
      do over arr;
         arr = ceil(rand('uniform')*100);
      end;
      output;
   end;
run;

data want;
   set have end=lr;
   array arr _25--_100;
   output;
   if lr;
   do over arr;
      arr = arr / 2;
   end;
   do _N_ = 1 to 20;
      z + 1;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: You can show me, if the name of the variable is like: _25, _26... _100; how should I modify the code "array arr a--c;"? is it like array arr _25-_100?; thanks

Comment: You can use name literals if you want to, but it is not recommended. e.g. '1'n, '2'n, etc.